# PostgreSQL: Use parameter of function in where clause

Tags: postgresql, function, view, parameters

I want to create a **function that uses a filter-parameter**, that is later applied to a where-clause.

The definition of my function so far looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_to_be_fixed(filter_date date)                   
RETURNS void as  $$
Begin
  CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_to_create.randomname AS
  SELECT * from other_table where date_col <= filter_date
End;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When calling the function via

```
 select function_to_be_fixed(filter_date   => '2020-01-01');
```

I receive the error: column 'filter_date' does not exist.

What do I need to adjust in order to make it run?

Comment: As I have commented on your other question as well: Why do you want to create thousands of views? Providing a set returning function that returns the desired sub-set of the table looks like a much easier way to do this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I need to pull data from the database using python. The request contains a filterdate, that is variable. Is there another nice way to do this without a function?

Comment: What's wrong with a function? Surely python can call functions in a SQL statement? `select * from get_data('2020-01-01');`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: all right - so your suggestion would be a function, that does not create a view but returns a table, right?
So how does the return type of that function look like - if thousands of views are not what seems to be appropriate?

Comment: I have added an example to my answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: many thanks for that! Final question:will that example work if I have a join, that uses data from multiple tables - and not one single table?

Comment: yes, you can join to the result of such a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a parameter like that inside the view definition.

Once the view is created the parameter would be "lost".

You need to use dynamic SQL for that, so that the value of the parameter is replace into the SQL string that defines the view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_to_be_fixed(filter_date date)                   
RETURNS void as  $$
Begin
  execute format('
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_to_create.randomname AS
    SELECT * from other_table where date_col <= %L', filter_date);
End;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

A single function that you pass the filter_date to would a better solution:

```
create or replace function get_some_table_data(filter_date date)
  returns setof some_table
as
$$
  select *
  from some_table
  where date_col <= filter_date;
$$
language sql;
```

Comment: Many thanks for the comprehensive reply!
I just tested your suggestion for my purposes - having two tables -  and recalled that one needs to slightly adapt the exaple. Correct me if I'm wrong, but one then has to state the definition of each column: e.g.     RETURNS table (col1 as integer, col2 integer) as $$